# how to get "0" value to show up with ng-show?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get a zero value to show up in angular UI.

```
<ng-show ng-show="item._source.change.backOrdered"><br> {{'pages.items.backOrdered' | translate}} {{item._source.change.backOrdered}}</ng-show>
```

So there's 2 cases - when the value is undefined it shouldn't display. But when the value is 0 it should be displayed.

Is there a trick to make this work, like convert the zero to string or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ng-show=var != null`:

```
<ng-show ng-show="item._source.change.backOrdered != null">
    <br> {{'pages.items.backOrdered' | translate}} {{item._source.change.backOrdered}}
</ng-show>
```

Comment: I used this, it seems to work. can accept answer in 7 minutes apparently :)

Comment: Are you sure this works with a field that type is undefined (typeof obj.field === undefined, which means, it does not exist) also? 
For me the solution above wir angular.isNumber(obj.field) does the job

Answer (score 1):

i think you can use [`angular.isNumber`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isNumber)

js:

```
$scope.isNumber = function(value){
  return angular.isNumber(value);
}
```

html:

```
<ng-show ng-show="isNumber(item._source.change.backOrdered)"><br> {{'pages.items.backOrdered' | translate}} {{item._source.change.backOrdered}}</ng-show>
```